# How to extract it from HTML with Python?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to extract that data:

```
<div class="address"><h3>Text1</h3><div class="adr">Text2</div></div>
```

I want to print text1 and text2.

I try this:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
html = """<div class="address"><h3></h3><div class="adr"></div></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open("http://de.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-gr-gr.php")
adress = soup.findAll('div', attrs={ "class" : "adr"})

print len(adress)
```

I am getting as Result:

```
1

...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to, first, make a request using `mechanize` and only then pass the `response` to the `BeautifulSoup` for parsing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.122 Safari/537.36')]
br.open("http://de.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-gr-gr.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())
address = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "address"})

print address.h3.text.strip()
print address.find('div', attrs={'class': 'adr'}).text.strip()
```

Prints:

```
Jan Amsel
Invalidenstrasse 6567159 Friedelsheim
```

Comment: Thanks that works for the adress, but I am not getting the h3.

Comment: Could you tell me one more.. trying to get the phone number on the website to. And text.strip() says: print tel.find('span', attrs={"class": "value"}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ..... do it says no text because it is numbers?

Comment: @Jerome for the phone try this one `print soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'tel'}).span.text.strip()`.